# SQLAlchemy unitest using json as a fixture

Tags: django, sqlalchemy

Unitest cases are very useful especially for the projects which lack in the UI part.
I Did the unitest cases in Django which is very easy.First to Dump the table data using indent into json

```
python manage.py dumpdata --indent=4  APP_NAME > FILENAME.json
```

Then using this Fixture in Testcases.

```
class MyAppTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['FILENAME.json']

    def test_index(self):
              pass
```

I was looking for something same in SQLAlchemy.
SQLAlchemyFixture are okay but not as good as Django approach to use the testcases using fixture in json.
Do any one has any approach to do same in SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0):

Using fixture you can dump database content into similar object but python module instead of json. See http://farmdev.com/projects/fixture/using-fixture-cmd.html